# Cannot Create User With MySQL

Tags: mysql, bash, mariadb

I am working on a bash script to create databases and users on the mysql database.

For that, I am trying to create databases and users. Databases works just fine, but creating users and granting rights to these users does not work.

I tried to write it in caps, not in caps, to copy and paste several results from the internet.

```
root@hosting:/bin# mysqladmin -u root password supersecretpassword  CREATE USER 'testuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
mysqladmin: CREATE DATABASE failed; error: 'Can't create database 'USER'; database exists'

mysqladmin: CREATE DATABASE failed; error: 'Can't create database 'USER'; database exists'
root@hosting:/bin# mysqladmin -u root password supersecretpassword GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON testdb.* TO testuser@localhost;
mysqladmin: Unknown command: 'GRANT'
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: Had you read mysqladmin's parameter reference, you would know that the create parameter is for creating databases and cannot be used for anything else. Mysqladmin cannot execute an arbitrary sql statement, that's not what that utility is for.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysql` command and the `-e` option before your statements.

Example:

```
mysql -u root -p supersecretpassword -e "CREATE USER 'testuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';"
```

See [execute option](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_execute) for more information and options.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to pass the SQL command with the -e argument of mysql command:

```
mysql -h <hostname> -u <username> -p <db_name> -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON testdb.* TO testuser@localhost"
```